# resolving and instantiating non imported packages with --run and --macro include

Tags: macros, haxe

I've been using the --run command, and have been trying to include some packages
when running it, using --macro include like this:

```
haxe -lib nape --macro include('nape.geom.Vec2') --run Main 'nape.geom.Vec2'
```

and then use Type.resolve so I can instantiate them with Type.createInstance like so:

```
class Main 
{
  static function main() 
  {
    trace("hello", Sys.args());
    var c = Type.resolveClass(StringTools.replace(Sys.args()[0], "'", ""));
    trace(c);
    Type.createInstance(c, []);
  }
}
```

I've also tried to use --interp with this command:

```
haxe -lib nape --macro include('nape.geom.Vec2') -main Main --interp -D nape.geom.Vec2
```

They both run, trace, and receive the Sys.args as expected for --run (with a small code change to accommodate '-D nape.geom.Vec2' for interp), but resolveClass always returns null, so I cant pass it to creatInstance without an error.

I'm using haxe 3.4.2 stable

What am I doing wrong? Is this possible with the --run command or --interp commands?

Id really love some more complete documentation on some of these features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got it working by linking the individual classes I require, and disabling dead code elimination (as suggested above by Jonas Malaco)

Using the code from the original post, and this build command:

`haxe -lib nape nape.geom.Vec2 -dce no --run Main 'nape.geom.Vec2'`

Answer (score 1):

The 'include' macro includes a package, not a class.

It works with:

```
haxe -lib nape --macro include('nape.geom') --run Main 'nape.geom.Vec2'
```

See http://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/Compiler.html#include

Comment: Running that command, it's still returning null for the class type. Any ideas?

Comment: @ediblebird, [dead code elimination](https://haxe.org/manual/cr-dce.html) perhaps?  Maybe compiling with `-D dce-debug` yields some useful information.  For single classes, you can also directly include them in the command line/build.hxml: `haxe -lib nape nape.geom.Vec2 --run Main 'nape.geom.Vec2'`

Comment: Directly including single classes and adding `-dce no` seemed to do the trick!